# .NET 4.0 application on network share causes SecurityException

Tags: c#, .net, clr, .net-4.0, securityexception

Today I experienced a weird problem while trying to remotely debug an application built for the .NET 4.0 runtime.

The application resides on a network share and executed by a remote machine. However the application crashes each time during load because of a SecurityException raised by a permission demand in the System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection() method. I have not checked if other permission demands in the base class library also cause a security exception but in all cases this shouldn't be happening with the new CLR.

The application is running in full trust (checked it while debugging and as usual this must be always true for intranet applications in CLR 4.0) so I am clueless how a permission demand can cause an exception in this case. When built against the 3.5 SP1 runtime (which first introduced full trust for network shared apps by default) everythings runs as expected.

I pasted the sample code below. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
public sealed class AssetsSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    private static readonly ConfigurationProperty           s_propPath;
    private static readonly ConfigurationPropertyCollection s_properties;

    static AssetsSection()
    {
        s_propPath = new ConfigurationProperty("path", typeof(String));

        s_properties = new ConfigurationPropertyCollection()
        {
            s_propPath
        };
    }

    public static AssetsSection Get()
    {
        return (AssetsSection) ConfigurationManager.GetSection("test/assets");
    }

    protected override ConfigurationPropertyCollection Properties
    {
        get
        {
            return s_properties;
        }
    }

    public String Path
    {
        get
        {
            return (String) base[s_propPath];
        }
        set
        {
            base[s_propPath] = value;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(AssetsSection.Get().Path);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

And the App.config file;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="test">
        <section name="assets" type="ConsoleApplication1.AssetsSection, ConsoleApplication1"/>
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client"/>
</startup>

<test>
    <assets path="..\Assets"/>
</test>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Why do you build for .NET 4.0 but force it to run an old version of the CLR?

Comment: Sorry I pasted the wrong config file from my test code. I edited the question. However the problem still remains of course.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try loading the configuration first and open your section on that:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
AssetsSection configSection = (AssetsSection)config.GetSection("test/assets");
```

I ran into the same issue with .NET 4 and this works for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot Timo. It also worked for me. But I assume this is a bug in .NET 4.0.

Comment: Note that while this works around the exception, there is a performance issue: the deserialized xml is NOT cached and happens each time you call OpenExeConfiguration(). The "right" (buggy) way using GetSection() caches the section XML and will reuse it in subsequenct calls. This may or may not affect performance in your app, depending on how performance sensitive it is and how often you make calls to OpenExeConfiguration.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to a known bug in .NET 4.0 when running the application from a network share.

The follow code fails with a SecurityException. Note that it only fails when you have defined a custom type for the section like in this example `AssetsSection`:

```
ConfigurationManager.GetSection("test/assets");
```

One fix is the solution suggestion by Timo to use a different API. Another solution is to apply the patch provided by Microsoft.

The bug and the related hotfix is filed under [KB2580188](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2580188).

Answer (score 1):

If you add your own class to map the section like this:

```
[XmlRoot("Interface")]
public class MySectionClass
{
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string MyAttr1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string MyAttr2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

You can use this code:

```
ConfigurationSection configSection = 
ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None).
GetSection("MySection");

XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MySectionClass));

XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(configSection.SectionInformation.GetRawXml());

XmlNodeReader xnr = new XmlNodeReader(xdoc.DocumentElement);

MySectionClass section = (MySectionClass)xs.Deserialize(xnr);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm speculating here, but I suspect it's your configuration file that's not trusted.

In your case, your configuration file is referencing a type `ConsoleApplication1.AssetsSection` that does not have a strong name that could be used as evidence.

Can you provide more details and the exact error message.

Comment: I have the same problem, my app config look like this and I still have the problem <section name="AuthenticationSection" type="Cnbv.Sait.Configuration.AuthenticationConfigurationSection, Cnbv.Sait.Configuration, Version=4.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=51d456dd8a5ff4be" requirePermission="false" />