# Get Configuration section

Tags: c#, windows-services, app-config, configurationmanager

I have a desktop app which I need to test my windows service with.

The application just call a windows service class which handle my business, First it should load some data from app.config.

The app config is within the sevice project and I store my confugration in a custom section [ABCConfigurationSection].
Like ...

```
<ABCConfigurationSection>
    <ConnectSettings>
      <clear />
      <add key="HostIp" value="10.0.X.X"/>
    </ConnectSettings>
 </ABCConfigurationSection>
```

The main config section is like ..

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="ABCConfigurationSection" type="ABCConfiguration, App.Core" />
  </configSections>
</configuration>
```

When I retrive the configuration sections passing the "ABCConfigurationSection" as section name I got null ! 
Any idea about if the strcture of the app config is missing something

Comment: Can you show the code, how you are calling?

Comment: section = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("ABCConfigurationSection") as App.Core.ABCConfiguration;

Answer (score 0):

In your configSections, for the section "ABCConfigurationSection", you declare that a type called "ABCConfiguration" is the type that handle your section.

This means, that in your code, you should define a class named ABCConfiguration derived from ConfigurationSection that read your section.

There are numerous details on this subject. This is a link to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) where a full example is given

Comment: I have that class and I use it with another application - web application - with no error and no problem.
The problems just when using with in the win-service

Comment: Could you check the file properties of your config file?. This is a similar problem: [TypeInitializationException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452077/typeinitializationexception-when-starting-windows-service-because-config-section)

Comment: I don't think, My file properties isn't like what in the referd post! 
it's not read only,not hidden even without the unblock button