# Reading configuration section Failed

Tags: .net, app-config

I'm having a problem with some application. When I execute it in local disk all is right, but when I try to execute the same application from a shared resource (Z:\resource\TheApplication.exe) I got the following error:

```
Error occurred creating the configuration section handler for DOMAIN/DomainUserInfo: Request failed
```

The error occurs when trying to read a **custom section** in the **configuration file**:

```
public static class AppConfigFile {
    public static IDomainUserInfo DomainUserInfo {
        get {
            if (_domainUserInfo == null) {
                _domainUserInfo = (DomainUserInfo)ConfigurationManager.GetSection(Environment.UserDomainName + @"/DomainUserInfo");         
            } return _domainUserInfo as IDomainUserInfo;
        }
    }
}
public class DomainUserInfo : ConfigurationSection, IDomainUserInfo {
    [ConfigurationProperty("SomeConfiguration", IsRequired = true, DefaultValue = "")]
    public string SomeConfiguration { get { return (string)base["SomeConfiguration"]; } }    

    [ConfigurationProperty("OtherConfiguration", IsRequired = true, DefaultValue = "")]
    public string OtherConfiguration { get { return (string)base["OtherConfiguration"]; } }    
}
```

The configuration file looks like:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="THE_DOMAIN" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="DomainUserInfo" type="NameSpace.Other.DomainUserInfo,NameSpace.Other" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

    <THE_DOMAIN>
        <DomainUserInfo SomeConfiguration="SomeValue" OtherConfiguration="OtherValue"></DomainUserInfo>
    </THE_DOMAIN>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem you have described is caused by a [bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/559615/starting-application-from-network-share-and-access-config-section-fails) in application configuration functionality of .NET 4.0.

#### Edit

Link to bug is not available anymore approximately since release of Visual Studio 2012 due to re-design of [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/) website. I did not manage to find defect on new *Microsoft Connect* anymore and do not remember its number.

The only thing I have managed to find is that link to that bug still remains in *Google*'s cache.

[image: Bug's entry in Google's cache]

As a work around it helped for me to open *Application Configuration* with code:

```
configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

and then read custom section with following code:

```
CustomSection1 customSection1 = (CustomSection1)configuration.GetSection("CustomSection1");
```

**Note :** Work around was found by me in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2800972/894174) to similar question.

Comment: @JasonDuffett Have updated the answer - I did not manage to find link to that defect of .NET after redesign of *Connect* website by Microsoft.

Comment: The bug still exists in the current versions of .NET 4.0 but there is a (difficult to find!) Hotfix available at: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2580188

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared `OtherConfiguration` in your class. Therefore, you cannot have it as an attribute on the `DomainUserInfo` in your config.

Comment: Suppose [OtherConfiguration] is also declared, I have included only some part of my code. I thing the problem is related with security concerns.