# System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal class in Portable Class Libraries

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, portable-class-library

I have a problem with the `Marshal` class in the `System.Runtime.InteropService`namespace.
In my project map I have a Windows Phone 8, a Windows Store and a Portable Class Library project. 
I can easily use the `Marshal`class in the Windows Phone 8 and Windows Store project, but not in the Portable Class Library. This class can not be found there.

By settings, the Portable Class Library support the .Net 4.5 Framework, Windows Phone OS 8.0 and Windows Store.

Comment: Take a look on this [entry at Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/762323/marshal-class-missing-in-portable-class-library).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access `Marshal` class in *Portable Class Library* project with support of anything else than *.NET Framework* and *Windows Store App* - by design of .NET Framework as stated in [resolution of relevant bug of .NET Framework](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/762323/marshal-class-missing-in-portable-class-library).

Added below a screenshot as at [MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com) they tend to delete defects (as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444847/reading-configuration-section-failed/9041111#9041111)) from time to time:
[image]

Comment: That's what I noticed. But why? This is totally illogical.